# Passing variable from controller with redirect/ route to view- Laravel 5.2 - getting an undefined variable error

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display a message -that is in my userController.

--inside my userController

```
$file = $request->file['image'];

    if($file){

        $debugMsg = "yes";

    } else {
        $debugMsg = "no";
    }return redirect()->route('perfil', $debugMsg);
```

-- inside my 'perfil'

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="test-box container"> 
        <h1>Debugging message here: {{ $debugMsg }}</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

Getting an undefined variable error.

Comment: nope that example is different, tried using with(); - could not pass variable.

Comment: I´m using the return redirect()->route('perfil', $debugMsg);

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
return redirect()->route('perfil', $debugMsg);
```

instead of

```
return redirect()->route('perfil', ['debugMsg' => $debugMsg]);
```

In your view use

```
{{ $debugMsg }}
```

instead of

```
{ $debugMsg }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried  {{ $debugMsg }} and I get an Undefined variable: debugMsg

Comment: Take a look to the variables in the view, so you can see which variables are received in the view. {{ dd(get_defined_vars()) }} In which directory do you have your view and what is its name?

Comment: @OzmaTis: Try to use $debugMsg out of your if statement. Hope the solution will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a view, so in your controller you have to use

```
    return view('perfil', ['debugMsg' => $debugMsg]);
```

In the view you can show this variable using

```
{{ $debugMsg }}
```

Add the variable definition out of the "if"

```
$debugMsg = '';
if($file){
    $debugMsg = "yes";
} else {
    $debugMsg = "no";
}
```

Comment: I tried with 'return view()' and - {{!!  $debugMsg !!}} but i get an undefined varaiable error -

Comment: I think the problem could be with if($file)  - i did this                                     'if($file){

   $user->perfil_img = $filename;
   $user->update(); }'

Comment: @OzmaTis Add the variable definition out of the "if"

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I finally found the error I made. The problem was in the if($error), after extensivly going through my code and some online tutorials I noticed that I was missing--- enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form tag, I found out that the $file =$request->('image') was not retriving the file-type in the input tag. Sorry for wasting your time with my noob-ity.

Hope this thread will also help someone.. assuming others are as stupid as me lol.